# How to write back the variables in a tcl readable format to the file intelligently using tcl in the same format

Tags: tcl

This code has a class named class1 and methods set, get, load, save

```
# Class1 definition
oo::class create class1 {
    variable dataArr

    method set {key value} {
        set dataArr($key) $value
    }

    method get {key} {
        if {[info exist dataArr($key)]} {
            return $dataArr($key)
        }
    }

    method load {} {
        set fp [open /home/karthikc/data.tcl r]
        set file_data [read $fp]
        puts $file_data
        eval  $file_data
        close $fp
    }

    method save {{newFilePath ""}} {
        if [info exists filePath] {
            set tmpFP $filePath  
        }
        if {$newFilePath ne ""} { 
            set tmpFP $newFilePath
        }

        if ![info exists tmpFP] {
            puts"neither newFilePath argument is passed nor filePath variable is present"
            return 0
        } 

        try {
            set fhandle [open $tmpFP w]

            if ![info exists dataArr] {
                puts "dataArr variable doesn't exist in the object [self]"
                return 0
            }
            foreach key [array names dataArr] {
                set kvPair [list $key $dataArr($key)]
                lappend dataLst $kvPair
                puts $fhandle "my set $key $dataArr($key)"
                puts "my set $key $dataArr($key)"
            }


            set filePath $tmpFP
            puts "dictionary is successfully saved in the file path"
        } on error {result opts} {
            puts $result
            puts "Return options Directory"
            puts $opts
            return 0
        } finally {
            if [info exist fhandle] {
                close $fhandle
            }
        }
        return 1
    }
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
# create object instance
set obj [class1 new]

# call load method
$obj load

# call save method
$obj save /home/karthikc/data.tcl
```

my `data.tcl` is

```
my set key1 value1
my set key2 value2
my set key3 [list valueA valueB valueC]
my set key4 [list valueX [list valueY valueZ]]
```

I want to write back to same format or some other list of lists

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestions for improvement

You can simplify your SERIALIZER, and render it more robust along the way.

First, don't serialize the object's state into a script, but a literal map (associative array or dict in Tcl). And read it as such:

`data.tcl` could look like:

```
key3 {valueA valueB valueC}
key4 {valueX {valueY valueZ}}
key1 value1
key2 value2
```

Your `load` method could use `array set` to read this directly:

```
method load {} {
  set fp [open /tmp/data.tcl r]
  set file_data [read $fp]
  array set dataArr $file_data
  close $fp
}
```

Your `save` method can directly use `array get` and produce formatted output:

```
method save2 {{newFilePath ""}} {
  if {[array exists dataArr]} {
    set fhandle [open $newFilePath w]
    set out ""
    foreach {k v} [array get dataArr] {
      append out $k " " [list $v] \n
    }
    puts $fhandle $out
    close $fhandle
  }
}
```

Key to the idea is to avoid `eval`, and, therefore, code injection. And the serialization format matches 1:1 first-class Tcl data structures.

### Improving your question

Allow me to say, your question is not a proper question. It does not state a problem, one has to read between the lines and snippets to sense what you are after. Also, the code example should be reduced to a minimum, to demonstrate your perceived problem. It is not helpful to paste your entire code work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the format of storing the lists 
from

```
my set key1 value1
my set key2 value2
my set key3 [list valueA valueB valueC]
my set key4 [list valueX [list valueY valueZ]]
```

to

```
my set key1 value1
my set key2 value2
my set key3 {valueA valueB valueC}
my set key4 {valueX {valueY valueZ}}
```

and in save method I changed

```
puts $fhandle "my set $key $dataArr($key)"
```

to

```
puts $fhandle [list my set $key $dataArr($key)]
```

And these changes serve the purpose.